# Compressing a Vector3 list by calculating delta positions in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am recording a long list of object positions and rotations to file and the result is a very large file. I was wondering if it would be possible to compress this file by recording the change in position/rotation rather than the absolute value. Here's what I'm imagining:

1. For the first element, store the absolute position and rotation for each object.
2. For subsequent elements, calculate the delta position (pos2 - pos1) and store that. Do a similar thing for the quaternion rotations (not sure exactly how yet).

My question is, if I calculate a delta Vector3 for positions, does that actually take up any less disk space than an absolute Vector3 position? Is a Vector3 a set number of bytes? If so, is there a better data structure I can use?

Comment: `Vector3` is a fixed size, so this would not help you. Define "long" and "large".

Comment: @RetiredNinja - I'm sending the file over the internet, so the smaller the better. It seems to me that it's inefficient to store the entire global positions for each element when all I really need is the change in position.

Comment: "Absolute positions" are just relative to 0,0,0. So that makes no difference. You could ZIP the file instead

Comment: @Xerillio - I'm already compressing the file. The positions being recorded are all very similar to each other, so I'd imagined that storing positions relative to each other would be more efficient than storing positions relative to 0,0,0.

Comment: A `float` or `double` is the same size no matter the content of the variable. Are you recording these values as text or binary data? How do you write them to the file?

Comment: A `Vector3` will take up the same space regardless of whether or not the position it stores is absolute or relative. The size is based on the *type*, not the *data*, just as the int `2147483647` takes the same space as the int `0`.

Comment: @spobin Try to create a class that takes X,Y,Z values as [sbyte](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.sbyte?view=net-5.0). Make it serializable and you can send it over server. **sbyte** is betwee -128 and +127. You can divide transform positions to your maximum position size so it will be between 0 and 1. Or if you have a grid system divide it to grid size.

Comment: @spobin Also, it would be much better, if you add what server protocol do you use and how do you store,compress and send the data.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa that sbyte method sounds interesting. I'll look into that and flesh out my question with some more code to make it clearer, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

As stated in my comment "absolute position" are just relative to `(0, 0, 0)`. Sure, you may be able to make the numbers smaller by calculating their position relative to another point/object that is closer to or at the centroid of all the points. In C#, however, `8.5` uses just as many bytes of storage as `12345.6789` if both are stored as a `float` type. So the naïve approach of just transforming the positions relative to another object won't get you all the way.

If, however, you can safely convert all the numbers to a datatype that uses fewer bytes, then yes, you can save some bytes of storage. But that requires *all* numbers to have a limited number of significant figures ("number of digits"), otherwise you would lose information by using a smaller datatype.

Alternatively, you can dive into doing your own "encoding" of the data to use as few bits as possible to represent the points and rotations.

Both options I imagine will be a headache for you to try to implement, so I think your best option is to focus on standard file compression or upgrade the storage capacity on the server. If storage is the issue.

Comment: This is the worst advice can be given. OP stated he wants to compress file because he is sending data over network and you suggest he needs more local storage. Also in Vector3 world position, after 2 significant figure nothing matters most of the time. Also probably in OPs case I bet even any decimal is useless or negligible. Thats why I suggested a class that uses 3 sbyte field in my comment on question.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa as long as OP doesn't specify the exact requirements you can't just jump to the conclusion that the positions or deltas are only needed in a certain precision though ;)

Comment: @SeLeCtRa 1: I never mentioned local storage, but I understand why mentioning "HDD/SSD" may lead you to those thoughts. I'll clarify. 2: "significant figures" refer to more than the figures after the decimal separator. `12345.678` has 8 significant figures. Using `sbyte` as you mentioned will limit you severely to only have 256 different positions on each axis, although yes, perhaps OP doesn't need more precision but I highly doubt it since he mentions having a lot of objects. I'd like to know more about why you believe this is the "worst advice" if you wouldn't mind elaborating.

Comment: @Xerillio If you have read my comment carefully, I said to OP he can divide vector axis value to maximum value so it will yield value between 0 and 1. Also for decimals each axis can have 2 value, one for mantissa and one for decimal part. And because it is sbyte it is far efficient than float value.

Comment: @SeLeCtRa I believe I've been careful in my reading. But normalizing the vectors (dividing by max value as you say) still doesn't seem to fix the issue that an sbyte is an 8-bit signed integer which means you only have 1/255th precision along each axis which is a very low precision if we imagine a typical video game world. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your descriptions, so I'll suggest you propose an answer instead, which I imagine the OP will greatly appreciate.